# Blinking LED effect using FillEllipse

Tags: c#, wpf, wpf-controls

I want to use the FillEllipse & DrawEllipse function to act like a LED display. But I was not able to click on the button to disable the blinking again since the subroutine is still running. Any recommendation?

```
    bool alert = false;
    bool blink = false;

    private void blinking()
    {
        Graphics pb = pictureBox1.CreateGraphics();
        SolidBrush red = new SolidBrush(Color.Red);
        SolidBrush green = new SolidBrush(Color.LightGreen);
        while (blink == true)
        {
            pictureBox1.Refresh();
            if (alert == true)
            {
                pb.FillEllipse(red, 20, 20, 50, 50);
                alert = false;  
            }
            else
            {
                //pb.FillEllipse(green, 20, 20, 50, 50);                    
                pb.DrawEllipse(Pens.Red, 20, 20, 50, 50);
                alert = true;
            }
            Thread.Sleep(timer1.Interval);
        }

    }

    private void blink_btn_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (blink == false)
        {
            blink = true;
        }
        else
        {
            blink = false;
        }
        blinking();

    }
```

Comment: @GrantWinney Hi, may i know where should i put the Timer? Do you mind showing me the solution? Thanks you.

Comment: Its something like a fire alarm security system. I was reading on a pci I/O card to determine the alarm was trigger or not. If alarm trigger happened, the ellipse has to start blinking.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Besides that you are blocking the UI with your `blinking()` method, you're not drawing correctly anyway. You should *only* draw when handling a `Paint` event. Also, there's not really a good reason to use a `PictureBox` if all you're going to do is draw something yourself. Just put a `Panel`, or even make a custom control.

But, sticking with the "draw into the PictureBox" approach, this is what your code really ought to look like:

First, it looks like you already have a `Timer` attached to the form. Why you're not already using that is beyond me, but you should. Hook up a handler to the `Tick` event:

```
private void timer1_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    alert = !alert;
    pictureBox1.Invalidate();
}
```

Add your handler for the `PictureBox.Paint` event:

```
private void pictureBox1_Paint(object sender, PaintEventArgs e)
{
    Brush brush = alert ? Brushes.Red : Brushes.LightGreen;

    e.Graphics.FillEllipse(brush, 20, 20, 50, 50);
}
```

Finally, use your button `Click` handler to toggle the timer:

```
private void blink_btn_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    timer1.Enabled = !timer1.Enabled;
}
```

Add code as necessary to draw differently (the above just toggles between the red and green ellipse), to reset the appearance when the timer's not active, etc.